# How to validate Dynamic angularJs form table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this following code:

```
<div class="table-responsive" ng-if="form.productDetails != false">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="small">
                <th class="col-xs-1">Name of Product/th>
                    <th class="col-xs-1">Price</th>
                    <th class="col-xs-1">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="productDetails in form.productDetails.item">
                <td ng-form="prductForm"><input type="hidden"       name="productDetails" required ng-model="form.mainProductDetails.productDetails" ng-value="{{productDetails.name}}"></td>
                <td>{{productDetails.name}}</td>
                <td>{{productDetails.price}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="editProduct(productDetails)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Edit</button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="removeProduct(productDetails)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now I want to make the table or the columns required and table will be only validate if there is any data exists in the table columns.

I have added this hidden input field which needs to be required. based on data passed from ng-repeat the validation should be done.

I have seen many examples but not quite sure how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the table if there are any `form.productDetails`?

Comment: There is nothing to be validated I guess...No input field...

Comment: I want to make these required as this is a part of another form which appears when it makes the condition. I was trying to solve it like this:<input type="hidden" name="productDetails" required ng-model="form.mainProductDetails.productDetails" ng-value={{productDetails.productName}}>    but didn't work